# Prevent 'cleartool.exe update' on snapshotview to leave .keep files & folders?

Tags: clearcase, config-spec

Is there any way to update a CC snapshot view (after changing the config spec) with the newer config spec removing some files from the view that existed with the previous config spec?

Basically what happens is that after the update I have numerous `.keep` folders/files and I know upfront that I do not want to have these.

Right now I do a *`cleartool.exe update -force -overwrite 'path to snapshotview'`*, but I was wondering whether there's an option to prevent creation of `.keep` artifacts?

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge:

You need to explicitly specify the **`-overwrite`** option for the **[`cleartool update`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_update.htm)** command to be sure no .keep will be generated (associated with **`-force`** as you mention in your question).

The only option you can unselect to avoid `.keep` file if for the undo-checkout (where you can specify you don't want backup file by default).
That doesn't apply to view updates though.

Comment: Hrm... I don't see an -override option in the linked documentation and cleartool.exe doesn't recognize it under the update subcommand either...

Comment: @Jörg B: it was a typo ;) overwrite, not override. Basically the same options than the ones you are mentioning in your question.

Comment: Ah alright :) But that doesn't work... what I'm doing now is 'cleaning' up manually after the update and remove .keep folders & files but this is somewhat 'unpleasant'. Ah well.. thanks!